# LWC - Need to Show different data in Each row of custom table in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

[image]

Please Helpp...!!..I need to show data only in that row in which I am selecting from drop down, But here whenever I am selecting the record from drop down in one row, all the rows are showing same details.

```
.js

import { LightningElement,track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import CONTACT_FIRST_NAME from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.FirstName";
import CONTACT_LAST_NAME from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.LastName";
import CONTACT_PHONE from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.Phone";
import CONTACT_EMAIL from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.Email";
import CONTACT_ACC_NAME from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.Account.Name";
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/DemoController2.getContactss';


let FIELDS = [CONTACT_FIRST_NAME,CONTACT_LAST_NAME,CONTACT_PHONE,CONTACT_EMAIL,CONTACT_ACC_NAME];



export default class demo2 extends LightningElement {

    rowId;
    value = '';
    optionsArray = [];    
    data = []; 
    result = {};
    
  get options(){
      return this.optionsArray;
  }
    connectedCallback(){
        getContacts()
        .then(response=>{
        let arr = []; 
        for(var i=0 ; i<response.length ; i++){
            arr.push({ label : response[i].Name , value : response[i].Id })
        }

        this.optionsArray = arr;
        }) 

    }
   
    handleChnagedValue(event){
        this.value = event.detail.value;
        this.rowId = event.detail.value; 
        console.log('ID',this.rowId);            
}

@wire(getRecord, { recordId:'$value', fields: FIELDS })
wiredRecord({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        // if(this.rowId == document.getElementById('row1')){
        const { fields } = data
        Object.keys(fields).forEach(item => {
            let value = fields[item] && fields[item].displayValue ? fields[item].displayValue : fields[item].value
            this.result = { ...this.result, [item]: value }
        })
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
        console.log('result',this.result);
    // }
}

else if (error) {
    console.error(error)
}
}
}


.html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Contact Details" icon-name="standard:contact_list">
      <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
          <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th class="" scope="col">
                          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Contact Name">Contact Name</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">
                          <div class="slds-truncate" title="First Name">First Name</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Last Name">Last Name</div>
                          </th>
                          <th class="" scope="col">
                              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Phone">Phone</div>
                            </th>
                          <th class="" scope="col">
                              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Email">Email</div>
                            </th>
                          <th class="" scope="col">
                             <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name</div> 
                          </th>      
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <!-- <template for:each={arr} for:item="con">
                    <tr key={con.Id}>  
                 -->
                 <tr id="row1">
                          <td>
                             <lightning-combobox 
                            value={value}
                            placeholder = "Select Contact"
                            options={options}
                            onchange={handleChnagedValue}>    
                             </lightning-combobox>
                          </td>
                          <td>{result.FirstName}</td>
                          <td>{result.LastName}</td>
                          <td>{result.Phone}</td>
                          <td>{result.Email}</td>
                          <td>{result.Account}</td> 
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                             <lightning-combobox 
                            value={value}
                            placeholder = "Select Contact"
                            options={options}
                            onchange={handleChnagedValue}>    
                             </lightning-combobox>
                          </td>
                          <td>{result.FirstName}</td>
                          <td>{result.LastName}</td>
                          <td>{result.Phone}</td>
                          <td>{result.Email}</td>
                          <td>{result.Account}</td> 
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                             <lightning-combobox 
                            value={value}
                            placeholder = "Select Contact"
                            options={options}
                            onchange={handleChnagedValue}>    
                             </lightning-combobox>
                          </td>
                          <td>{result.FirstName}</td>
                          <td>{result.LastName}</td>
                          <td>{result.Phone}</td>
                          <td>{result.Email}</td>
                          <td>{result.Account}</td> 
                        </tr> 
                        
                      <!-- </template>   -->
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>   
  </lightning-card> 
  </template>



 .cls
    public with sharing class DemoController2 {
            @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
            public static List<Contact> getContactss() {
                List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact LIMIT 5];
                return conList;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your problem is in the html where you are using “result” and not “con” which is your key iterator variable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But how it is possible to do iteration in this, like I am also using combobox  in my table, can you guide me with an example , what changes should i do in my code